# Why is this optimized away by modern compilers for C++11 and higher

Tags: c++

I'm lost.. I wanted to play around with the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to experiment with multithreaded C code, and started with a simple piece of code. The code is compiled with `-O3`.

```
static int hang = 0;

void set_hang(int x) {
    hang = x;
}

void wait() {
    while (hang != 0) {
        // wait...
    }
}
```

To my surprise, this was the compiler output:

```
set_hang(int):
        mov     dword ptr [rip + hang], edi
        ret
wait():
        ret
```

It took me a while before I noticed that I was compiling the code as C++ instead of C. Switching to C gave me something what I would have expected:

```
set_hang:
        mov     DWORD PTR hang[rip], edi
        ret
wait:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR hang[rip]
        test    eax, eax
        je      .L3
.L5:
        jmp     .L5
.L3:
        ret
```

Thus, when compiled as C++, `wait()` always returns, no matter which value was passed before to `set_hang()`. I confirmed this by compiling and the code on my PC. This code immediately exists, while I would expect it to hang foreever:

```
int main(void) {
    set_hang(1);
    wait();
    return 0;
}
```

And indeed, if I compile this with `gcc` instead of with `g++`, it hangs.

I experimented with different compilers (Clang and GCC), and this only happens with Clang 12.0.0 or higer or GCC 10.1 or higher. If I pass `--std=c++98` also the code I would expect is emitted, so it seems to be something specific for C++11 and higher.

Removing the `static` keyword from the `hang` doesn't affect the emitted assembly.

What is happening here? It has been a few months since I wrote C++, so I might be missing some knowledge about the latest and greatest exotic C++ black magic, but this is really straightforward code. I'm clueless.

---

Edit: Even this program is optimized away completely:

```
// test.cpp
static int hang = 0;

static void set_hang(int x) {
    hang = x;
}

static void wait() {
    while (hang != 0) {
        // wait...
    }
}

int main(void) {
    set_hang(1);
    wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

For GCC version 10.3.0 on Ubuntu:

This command will hang: `g++ -O1 -o test test.cpp && ./test`

And this command won't: `g++ -O2 -o test test.cpp && ./test`

Comment: Generally speaking, modern compilers are free to optimize your code as if it were single-threaded code. From that perspective, it's clear that your `wait()` code will never enter the loop, so there's no point in even running it. The situation would probably change if you marked your field as `volatile` (at least that would be the keyword in Java -- sorry, I'm not a C++ guy).

Comment: I do know that modern versions of C++ define a memory model (inspired by the JVM's), and it probably was introduced in C++ 11. That's why new compilers feel free to make such assumptions while older ones do not.

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm afraid so. Wow.

Comment: I also did not know before trying out before answering.

Comment: Indeed, when compiled as C code with clang 5.0.0 or higher (with `-O3 --std=c11`), the while loop is optimized out. Even the latest version of GCC (11.2) won't optimize the loop out. So could we say that GCC doesn't completely conform to C11?

Comment: @Bart No. Not optimising something that the compiler is allowed to - but not required to - optimise doesn't imply non-conformance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of following rule:

> [intro.progress]
>
> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.

The compiler was able to prove that a program that enters the loop will never do any of the listed things and thus it is allowed to assume that the loop will never be entered.